# How do I set the result of find into a variable?

Tags: find

`find . | grep "B02_10m.tif$"`

When executing this snippet in the terminal, I am able to get all the files that ends with B02_10m.tif.
However I need this list as input for a c file to make some processing. The input must be a linux variable to pass it as part of the arguments for the script.

`./avg outAVG $files`
Where $files is the variable containing the result of the first snippet.

Is that possible? 
I Already tried:

```
files = $(find . | grep "B02_10m.tif$")

Command 'files' not found, did you mean:

  command 'file2' from deb file-kanji
  command 'file' from deb file

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

And it did not work.

Comment: How is your C program called? Do you give it all the filenames in one go, or can you call it many times, once for each filename? Are you looking for the TIFF files in the current directory only, or in all subdirectories? What shell are you using, `bash` or `zsh`? Storing the filenames in a string is most likely _not_ what you want to do.

Comment: Makefile
---------
avg: avg.c
 gcc -o avg avg.c -lm -I/usr/include/gdal -L/usr/lib -lgdal
run.sh
---------
root=/home/user/Dir/
files=$(ls $root*satelliteimages*)
./avg outAVG $files 
* 
* NULLVAL is < 0
* 
*/

Comment: This is the information found in the original script, but I want to replace the line ```files=$(ls $root*satelliteimages)``` for the results that I get when running the command find and the arguments I already presented.

Comment: Do consider adding properly formatted code to the actual question. Code in comments is very hard to read. Make sure that you add code _exactly the way it is_ (`$root*satelliteimages` looks strange).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the `bash` shell:

```sh
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob

./avg outAVG ./**/*B02_10m.tif
```

This would call your `avg` program with all the files in or below the current directory that have filenames ending in `B02_10m.tif`.  It does this by first enabling the `**` globbing pattern with `shopt -s globstar`.  This pattern matches "recursively" down into subdirectories.  If your TIFF files are in the *current* directory, you don't need the `**` bit of this pattern.

The other two shell options makes sure that globbing patterns matches hidden names and that they expand to nothing at all if there is no match, just to mimic what you're trying to do with `find`.

If you are using the `zsh` shell, then you may instead use

```sh
./avg outAVG ./**/*B02_10m.tif(.DN)
```

which would do the same.  Again, if you know the directory where the TIFF images are stored, you don't need the `**` bit of the pattern but can instead insert the correct path to that directory.

In any `sh`-like shell, if your files are in the directory named by `$dir`, you may use

```sh
./avg outAVG "$dir"/*B02_10m.tif
```

This would obviously not do a recursive search down into subdirectories of `$dir`.

---

Your approach does not work for two reasons:

1. You have a syntax error in the assignment to the `files` variable.  There can be no whitespace around the `=` in an assignment.
2. Correcting that syntax error, you are combining many separate filenames into a single string.  Doing this disregards the fact that filenames may well include spaces and characters usually used as shell wildcards.  When you later use `$files` unquoted, the shell would split the string inte several words on whitespace characters (by default) and then expand all words that looks like shell globbing patterns.  This would make your code misbehave if you don't always have very simple filenames.

For more information about these issues, see e.g.

- "[Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)" (related to using filenames printed by `find` for anything),
- "[Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)" (related to quoting variables), and
- "[Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)" (related to the use of `ls` in [one of your comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555302/how-do-i-set-the-result-of-find-into-a-variable-in-the-terminal/555307#comment1031341_555302)).

Answer (score 0):

```
files1=`find . | grep "B02_10m.tif$"`
```

can you try this?

Comment: You should use `$( ... )` instead of backticks. And your suggestion will fail badly if any of the matching files contains a space in its name.